# files comparison

Tags: file, matlab

I'm trying to compare 2 txt files to check files are equals otherwise, get the output and give difference (say that there are a diff line x)

I'm trying as follows:

```
fid1 = fopen(file_1, 'r');
fid2 = fopen(file_2, 'r');
lines1 = textscan(fid1,'%s','delimiter','\n');
lines2 = textscan(fid2,'%s','delimiter','\n');
lines1 = lines1{1};
lines2 = lines2{1};
fclose(fid1);
fclose(fid2);
tf = isequal(lines1,lines2); % this gives 0 or 1
```

I would like when the value is 0 (files are different) to localize the diff and give line where files are different or print content of difference.

Comment: why don't you just use the gnu diff utilities? https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/

Comment: @bdecaf : diff works on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to compare each element of the two cell arrays you have, not the whole cell arrays. You could do that with a loop in most languages, but of course MATLAB has many ways to avoid loops. Here, it is `cellfun`:

`cellfun(@isequal,lines1,lines2)`

(I left out the part where, if the two cell arrays are of unequal size, you have to shorten the longer one.) Then, `find` is useful for finding the first (or all) occurrence(s) of a certain value in any vector.

Comment: when files are differents ,cellfun(@isequal,lines1,lines2) return an error as size aren't equal

Comment: Yes, that is what I alluded to with "I left out the part where, if the two cell arrays are of unequal size, you have to shorten the longer one."

Comment: When you do `c{i}` or `v(i)` you can use vectors as index to get a vector again, e.g. `n=20;v(1:n)` will give you the first 20 elements of `v`. `length` and `min` will get you the `n` you need.

Comment: Sorry, but [you have come to the wrong place](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) if you do not expect help with a specific problem but only want others to solve your task for you.